# Extracting fields/values from a complicated dict/list registered variable

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which will register a variable in the end, an example of it is as attached. I need to extract three specific fields/values from it.

What we could do is to iterate each element via a loop. But, I am not sure of what actually separate each elements because it looks complicated to me, and which item I should loop on. I need the extracted just three fields for my next task.

If you want details on how the `results` variable is registered, my playbook is attached as well.

The variable contains 4 elements and I need to extract 3 fields from it:

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "results": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "cert_filepath": null,
                        "feature_flags": null,
                        "fields": [
                            "svm.name",
                            "nas.export_policy.name"
                        ],
                        "force_ontap_version": null,
                        "gather_subset": [
                            "storage/volumes"
                        ],
                        "hostname": "10.192.18.10",
                        "http_port": null,
                        "https": true,
                        "ignore_api_errors": null,
                        "key_filepath": null,
                        "max_records": 1024,
                        "ontapi": null,
                        "owning_resource": null,
                        "parameters": {
                            "name": "roger_test1"
                        },
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "state": null,
                        "use_python_keys": true,
                        "use_rest": "Always",
                        "username": "admin",
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "client": [
                            "1.1.1.1",
                            "1.1.1.2"
                        ],
                        "volumename": "roger_test1"
                    },
                    "1.1.1.1"
                ],
                "ontap_info": {
                    "storage_volumes": {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test1"
                            }
                        },
                        "num_records": 1,
                        "records": [
                            {
                                "_links": {
                                    "self": {
                                        "href": "/api/storage/volumes/079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": "roger_test1",
                                "nas": {
                                    "export_policy": {
                                        "name": "root_allow_anon_squash"
                                    }
                                },
                                "svm": {
                                    "name": "eos-nfs-3"
                                },
                                "uuid": "079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "cert_filepath": null,
                        "feature_flags": null,
                        "fields": [
                            "svm.name",
                            "nas.export_policy.name"
                        ],
                        "force_ontap_version": null,
                        "gather_subset": [
                            "storage/volumes"
                        ],
                        "hostname": "10.192.18.10",
                        "http_port": null,
                        "https": true,
                        "ignore_api_errors": null,
                        "key_filepath": null,
                        "max_records": 1024,
                        "ontapi": null,
                        "owning_resource": null,
                        "parameters": {
                            "name": "roger_test1"
                        },
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "state": null,
                        "use_python_keys": true,
                        "use_rest": "Always",
                        "username": "admin",
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "client": [
                            "1.1.1.1",
                            "1.1.1.2"
                        ],
                        "volumename": "roger_test1"
                    },
                    "1.1.1.2"
                ],
                "ontap_info": {
                    "storage_volumes": {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test1"
                            }
                        },
                        "num_records": 1,
                        "records": [
                            {
                                "_links": {
                                    "self": {
                                        "href": "/api/storage/volumes/079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": "roger_test1",
                                "nas": {
                                    "export_policy": {
                                        "name": "root_allow_anon_squash"
                                    }
                                },
                                "svm": {
                                    "name": "eos-nfs-3"
                                },
                                "uuid": "079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "cert_filepath": null,
                        "feature_flags": null,
                        "fields": [
                            "svm.name",
                            "nas.export_policy.name"
                        ],
                        "force_ontap_version": null,
                        "gather_subset": [
                            "storage/volumes"
                        ],
                        "hostname": "10.192.18.10",
                        "http_port": null,
                        "https": true,
                        "ignore_api_errors": null,
                        "key_filepath": null,
                        "max_records": 1024,
                        "ontapi": null,
                        "owning_resource": null,
                        "parameters": {
                            "name": "roger_test2"
                        },
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "state": null,
                        "use_python_keys": true,
                        "use_rest": "Always",
                        "username": "admin",
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "client": [
                            "2.2.2.2"
                        ],
                        "volumename": "roger_test2"
                    },
                    "2.2.2.2"
                ],
                "ontap_info": {
                    "storage_volumes": {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test2"
                            }
                        },
                        "num_records": 1,
                        "records": [
                            {
                                "_links": {
                                    "self": {
                                        "href": "/api/storage/volumes/5d3bee8a-5d64-4b24-a89e-2ab56d2f9911"
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": "roger_test2",
                                "nas": {
                                    "export_policy": {
                                        "name": "export_policy_rootsquash"
                                    }
                                },
                                "svm": {
                                    "name": "eos-nfs-3"
                                },
                                "uuid": "5d3bee8a-5d64-4b24-a89e-2ab56d2f9911"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "cert_filepath": null,
                        "feature_flags": null,
                        "fields": [
                            "svm.name",
                            "nas.export_policy.name"
                        ],
                        "force_ontap_version": null,
                        "gather_subset": [
                            "storage/volumes"
                        ],
                        "hostname": "10.192.18.10",
                        "http_port": null,
                        "https": true,
                        "ignore_api_errors": null,
                        "key_filepath": null,
                        "max_records": 1024,
                        "ontapi": null,
                        "owning_resource": null,
                        "parameters": {
                            "name": "roger_test3"
                        },
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "state": null,
                        "use_python_keys": true,
                        "use_rest": "Always",
                        "username": "admin",
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "client": [
                            "3.3.3.3"
                        ],
                        "volumename": "roger_test3"
                    },
                    "3.3.3.3"
                ],
                "ontap_info": {
                    "storage_volumes": {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test3"
                            }
                        },
                        "num_records": 1,
                        "records": [
                            {
                                "_links": {
                                    "self": {
                                        "href": "/api/storage/volumes/ed3466b1-a9f8-48cc-b11d-197e3f4f80d2"
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": "roger_test3",
                                "nas": {
                                    "export_policy": {
                                        "name": "rosq_kb"
                                    }
                                },
                                "svm": {
                                    "name": "eos-nfs-3"
                                },
                                "uuid": "ed3466b1-a9f8-48cc-b11d-197e3f4f80d2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The playbook registering the variable:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    login: &login
      hostname: "10.192.18.10"
      username: "admin"
      password: "netapp123"
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
  vars_files:
    - ./var_files_dir/vars_subelement.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Get the name of vserver/svm and export_policy upon the volume
      netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
        use_python_keys: true
        use_rest: Always
        gather_subset:
          - storage/volumes
        fields:
          - 'svm.name'
          - 'nas.export_policy.name'
        parameters:
          #name: "{{ item.0.volumename | default({}) }}"
          name: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
        <<: *login
      loop: "{{ volumes|subelements('client','skip_missing=True') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
      register: results
    - debug: var=results
```

Following is the code I tried. It doesn't work, but may be helpful for you to understand what I expect. I am not sure what I should write down exactly so I replaced indexes with question marks.

```yaml
client IP: results.results.item[?] 
export_policy: "{{ results.results.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[?].nas.export_policy.name }}"
vserver: "{{ results.results.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[?].svm.name }}"
```

I need to extract three fields from each elements. Here is an example of what I expect on first element. The fields are the same in next ones.

**expected fields for element 1:**

```yaml
results.results.item: 1.1.1.1
results.results.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[?].nas.export_policy.name: root_allow_anon_squash
esults.results.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[?].svm.name: eos-nfs-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each item in `results.results` (consider using a better register name...) and construct the expected result iteratively with `set_fact`.

Regarding your tries, you need to understand a bit better how to address list elements and to detect what is a list or not in your debugged variable. But the below example should help you on that path.

And regarding list indexes, Ansible is based on python and starts numbering at 0. Looking at the below should be pretty obvious.

You might also want to read [Using filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html) (note: `d` is an alias for `default`) and [limiting loop output with label](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) to understand some bits of the code.

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Extract some info demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your data on a single line for legibility
    results: {"changed":false,"msg":"All items completed","results":[{"ansible_loop_var":"item","changed":false,"failed":false,"invocation":{"module_args":{"cert_filepath":null,"feature_flags":null,"fields":["svm.name","nas.export_policy.name"],"force_ontap_version":null,"gather_subset":["storage/volumes"],"hostname":"10.192.18.10","http_port":null,"https":true,"ignore_api_errors":null,"key_filepath":null,"max_records":1024,"ontapi":null,"owning_resource":null,"parameters":{"name":"roger_test1"},"password":"VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER","state":null,"use_python_keys":true,"use_rest":"Always","username":"admin","validate_certs":false}},"item":[{"client":["1.1.1.1","1.1.1.2"],"volumename":"roger_test1"},"1.1.1.1"],"ontap_info":{"storage_volumes":{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test1"}},"num_records":1,"records":[{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes/079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"}},"name":"roger_test1","nas":{"export_policy":{"name":"root_allow_anon_squash"}},"svm":{"name":"eos-nfs-3"},"uuid":"079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"}]}}},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","changed":false,"failed":false,"invocation":{"module_args":{"cert_filepath":null,"feature_flags":null,"fields":["svm.name","nas.export_policy.name"],"force_ontap_version":null,"gather_subset":["storage/volumes"],"hostname":"10.192.18.10","http_port":null,"https":true,"ignore_api_errors":null,"key_filepath":null,"max_records":1024,"ontapi":null,"owning_resource":null,"parameters":{"name":"roger_test1"},"password":"VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER","state":null,"use_python_keys":true,"use_rest":"Always","username":"admin","validate_certs":false}},"item":[{"client":["1.1.1.1","1.1.1.2"],"volumename":"roger_test1"},"1.1.1.2"],"ontap_info":{"storage_volumes":{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test1"}},"num_records":1,"records":[{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes/079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"}},"name":"roger_test1","nas":{"export_policy":{"name":"root_allow_anon_squash"}},"svm":{"name":"eos-nfs-3"},"uuid":"079221a5-ee1f-11ea-b01c-00a098f470f6"}]}}},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","changed":false,"failed":false,"invocation":{"module_args":{"cert_filepath":null,"feature_flags":null,"fields":["svm.name","nas.export_policy.name"],"force_ontap_version":null,"gather_subset":["storage/volumes"],"hostname":"10.192.18.10","http_port":null,"https":true,"ignore_api_errors":null,"key_filepath":null,"max_records":1024,"ontapi":null,"owning_resource":null,"parameters":{"name":"roger_test2"},"password":"VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER","state":null,"use_python_keys":true,"use_rest":"Always","username":"admin","validate_certs":false}},"item":[{"client":["2.2.2.2"],"volumename":"roger_test2"},"2.2.2.2"],"ontap_info":{"storage_volumes":{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test2"}},"num_records":1,"records":[{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes/5d3bee8a-5d64-4b24-a89e-2ab56d2f9911"}},"name":"roger_test2","nas":{"export_policy":{"name":"export_policy_rootsquash"}},"svm":{"name":"eos-nfs-3"},"uuid":"5d3bee8a-5d64-4b24-a89e-2ab56d2f9911"}]}}},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","changed":false,"failed":false,"invocation":{"module_args":{"cert_filepath":null,"feature_flags":null,"fields":["svm.name","nas.export_policy.name"],"force_ontap_version":null,"gather_subset":["storage/volumes"],"hostname":"10.192.18.10","http_port":null,"https":true,"ignore_api_errors":null,"key_filepath":null,"max_records":1024,"ontapi":null,"owning_resource":null,"parameters":{"name":"roger_test3"},"password":"VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER","state":null,"use_python_keys":true,"use_rest":"Always","username":"admin","validate_certs":false}},"item":[{"client":["3.3.3.3"],"volumename":"roger_test3"},"3.3.3.3"],"ontap_info":{"storage_volumes":{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes?max_records=1024&fields=svm.name%2Cnas.export_policy.name&name=roger_test3"}},"num_records":1,"records":[{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/storage/volumes/ed3466b1-a9f8-48cc-b11d-197e3f4f80d2"}},"name":"roger_test3","nas":{"export_policy":{"name":"rosq_kb"}},"svm":{"name":"eos-nfs-3"},"uuid":"ed3466b1-a9f8-48cc-b11d-197e3f4f80d2"}]}}}]}
  
  tasks:
    - name: Create our new variable iteratively
      vars:
        current:
          client_ip: "{{ item.item.1 }}"
          export_policy: "{{ item.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records.0.nas.export_policy.name }}"
          vserver: "{{ item.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records.0.svm.name }}"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        stripped: "{{ stripped | d([]) + [current] }}"
      loop: "{{ results.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.1 }}"

    - name: Show result
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: stripped
```

results in:

```
PLAY [Extract some info demo] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create our new variable iteratively] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1.1.1.1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=1.1.1.2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2.2.2.2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=3.3.3.3)

TASK [Show result] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "stripped": [
        {
            "client_ip": "1.1.1.1",
            "export_policy": "root_allow_anon_squash",
            "vserver": "eos-nfs-3"
        },
        {
            "client_ip": "1.1.1.2",
            "export_policy": "root_allow_anon_squash",
            "vserver": "eos-nfs-3"
        },
        {
            "client_ip": "2.2.2.2",
            "export_policy": "export_policy_rootsquash",
            "vserver": "eos-nfs-3"
        },
        {
            "client_ip": "3.3.3.3",
            "export_policy": "rosq_kb",
            "vserver": "eos-nfs-3"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: It works very well. A couple of follow-ups on looping, which is hard for me to understand:
1. loop: "{{ export_info.results }}": did you mean loop over 4 elements in this example? Usually, I would expect "item" in "loop:", but you didn't use it. 
2. I know how loop_control/label works, but here, label: "{{ item.item.1 }}", can you please explain to me what each field between "." represents for, including the ".1"? 
3. You used "records.0". There is one and only one record here, correct? Thank you!!!

Comment: The questions make me think you need a bit of background on lists and dicts. A good ressource: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/. Now regarding the above points: 1 => I mean looping over every elements in the `results` list in your register. If you need to limit the number of elements to loop on, use [python slicing](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-slicing/) (e.g. `loop: "{{ results.results[0:3] }}"`). 2&3 => as already explained in my answer, list indexes start at 0. So index 1 is the second element in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use *json_query* and select what you want. For example,

```yaml
  ontap_info_query: >
    [].{client: item[1],
        nas: ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[].nas.export_policy.name,
        svm: ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[].svm.name}
  ontap_info: "{{ results.results|json_query(ontap_info_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ontap_info:
    - client: 1.1.1.1
      nas: [root_allow_anon_squash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    - client: 1.1.1.2
      nas: [root_allow_anon_squash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    - client: 2.2.2.2
      nas: [export_policy_rootsquash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    - client: 3.3.3.3
      nas: [rosq_kb]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
```

Make the searching easier and convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  ontap_info_dict: "{{ dict(ontap_info|
                            map(attribute='client')|
                            zip(ontap_info)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ontap_info_dict:
    1.1.1.1:
      client: 1.1.1.1
      nas: [root_allow_anon_squash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    1.1.1.2:
      client: 1.1.1.2
      nas: [root_allow_anon_squash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    2.2.2.2:
      client: 2.2.2.2
      nas: [export_policy_rootsquash]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
    3.3.3.3:
      client: 3.3.3.3
      nas: [rosq_kb]
      svm: [eos-nfs-3]
```

The below debug

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          client: {{ client }}
          nas: {{ ontap_info_dict[client].nas|first }}
          svn: {{ ontap_info_dict[client].svm|first }}
      vars:
        client: 1.1.1.1
```

gives what you're looking for

```yaml
  msg:
    client: 1.1.1.1
    nas: root_allow_anon_squash
    svn: eos-nfs-3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - resutls.json

  vars:

    ontap_info_query: >
      [].{client: item[1],
          nas: ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[].nas.export_policy.name,
          svm: ontap_info.storage_volumes.records[].svm.name}
    ontap_info: "{{ results.results|json_query(ontap_info_query) }}"
    ontap_info_dict: "{{ dict(ontap_info|
                              map(attribute='client')|
                              zip(ontap_info)) }}"

  
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ontap_info|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: ontap_info_dict|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          client: {{ client }}
          nas: {{ ontap_info_dict[client].nas|first }}
          svn: {{ ontap_info_dict[client].svm|first }}
      vars:
        client: 1.1.1.1
```